# Install build-essential in Docker image without having to do `apt-get update`?

Tags: docker, gcc, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which starts with the following:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Problem is, this layer is always changing, so when I run `docker build -t <mytag> .`, this layer (and subsequent ones) run again, which takes up significant time.

Is there a way to install `build-essential` in my Dockerfile in a layer which doesn't constantly change?

---

EDIT:
I had a COPY line before RUN, which I removed from the question as I didn't want to include the names of private files, but it didn't occur to me that that was what was making the build re-run from this step.

Comment: But then your image will not have the updated packages , is it acceptable to you.

Comment: It is for now - all I need is build-essential. Why, is there an alternative which doesn't involve continuously rebuilding layers because of updates I don't need?

Comment: If you re-run `docker build` on the Dockerfile you show, Docker's layer caching should keep it from re-running that `RUN` line.  Is there something else in the line that's changing?  Or do you have a `COPY` line before it?

Comment: @DavidMaze good catch - I did have a COPY later before it, and that was what was changing. I took it out of the question as it contained paths I possibly shouldn't be sharing publicly, sorry for not having tested this out as written first

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a base image which contains:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Build it:

```
docker build -t mybase .
```

Then use it for new images:

```
FROM mybase
```

Answer (score 3):

> "Is there a way to install build-essential in my Dockerfile in  a
> layer which doesn't constantly change?"

Even the question "having some age", is a case in which the construction of the image can be used in multiple stages. The code below uses an example with a Python App.

```
# first stage
FROM python:3.8 AS builder
COPY requirements.txt .

# install dependencies to the local user directory (eg. /root/.local)
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

# second unnamed stage
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /code

# copy only the dependencies installation from the 1st stage image
COPY --from=builder /root/.local /root/.local
COPY ./src .

# update PATH environment variable
ENV PATH=/root/.local:$PATH

CMD [ "python", "./server.py" ]
```

I hope it will be useful.

src: [Containerized Python Development – Part 1](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerized-python-development-part-1/)